# R: Quickly generate partial sequences

Tags: r, nlp, purrr

I'm looking to generate sequences of text based on training an RNN on text snippets (which I've done before in [articles like this](https://towardsdatascience.com/using-deep-learning-to-generate-offensive-license-plates-619b163ed937)).

One step is to take the snippets of text and break them up into subsequences to train the model on:

```
c("E","X","A","M","P","L","E")
```

would become

```
c("E")
c("E","X")
c("E","X","A")
...
```

My current method is to use a map on each word:

```
require(tidyverse)

data <- data_frame(id = c(1,2),word = list(c("E","X","A","M","P","L","E"), c("R","S","T","U","D","I","O")))

result <- data %>%
  pmap(function(id,word){
    subs <- map(1:length(word),function(i) word[1:i])
    data_frame(id = id, sub = subs)
  }) %>%
  bind_rows()
```

But this is **extremely slow** on large datasets. Is there a fast way to generate all of these partial sequences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `Reduce` with `accumulate=TRUE`

```
Reduce(c,a,accumulate = T)
[[1]]
[1] "E"

[[2]]
[1] "E" "X"

[[3]]
[1] "E" "X" "A"

[[4]]
[1] "E" "X" "A" "M"

[[5]]
[1] "E" "X" "A" "M" "P"

[[6]]
[1] "E" "X" "A" "M" "P" "L"

[[7]]
[1] "E" "X" "A" "M" "P" "L" "E"
```

Thus to include this in your data, you can do:

```
data%>%
  group_by(id)%>%
  mutate(word=list(Reduce(c,unlist(word),accumulate = T)))%>%
  unnest()
```

to do the same in `purrr` you use the function `accumulate`

`purrr::accumulate(a,c)`

Although this is a function in `purrr` it is basically calling the `Reduce` function. ie

```
purrr::accumulate
function (.x, .f, ..., .init) 
{
    .f <- as_mapper(.f, ...)
    f <- function(x, y) {
        .f(x, y, ...)
    }
    Reduce(f, .x, init = .init, accumulate = TRUE)#THIS IS USING THE BASE FUNCTION Reduce
}
<environment: namespace:purrr>
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the issue was with calling `data_frame` within the map function. Creating data frames is slow, apparently. It can be done much more quickly if you sacrifice using data frames and instead stick with lists:

```
result <- data %>%
  pmap(function(id,word){
    map(1:length(word),function(i) list(id = id, sub = word[1:i]))
  }) %>%
  purrr::flatten()
```

I was hoping I could turn it all into a `data_frame` at the end by using `bind_rows()` but for some reason that function doesn't work with list columns.

Answer (score 0):

Using lapply with Reduce might be even faster here

```
x <- lapply(data$word, function(w){
    Reduce(c, w, accumulate = TRUE)}
```

Then you can bind them back into a data_frame as such

```
id2 <- rep(id, unlist(lapply(x, length)))

data2 <- data_frame(id2, subs=unlist(x, recursive=FALSE))
```